# issues PowerShell POST request with body

Tags: powershell

I have a bit issue with powershell + invoke-webrequest

This is my body

```
$pram = @{
   "name": "MDE.Windows",
   "id": "$resourceId/extensions/MDE.Windows",
   "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
   "location": "westeurope",
   "properties": {
     "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
     "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.AzureDefenderForServers",
     "type": "MDE.Windows",
     "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
     "settings": {
       "azureResourceId": "$resourceId",
       "defenderForServersWorkspaceId": "$subscriptionId",
       "vNextEnabled": "true",
       "forceReOnboarding": true,
       "provisionedBy": "Manual"
     },
     "protectedSettings": {
       "defenderForEndpointOnboardingScript": "$defenderForEndpointOnboardingScript"
     }
   }
 }
```

I don't get watch wrong with my body because by looking examples from google this should be right but it still ouputs red

[image]

I have tried also with `@"{ }"@, @'{ }'@, { }, "{ }"` but no matter what I do it is more or less red.

Comment: Powershell uses `=` to separate the key and value in a hashtable(not `:`)

Comment: See the conceptual [about_Hash_Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) help topic, which explains PowerShell's hashtable-literal syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mistaking powershell hash tables for json.  Normally you would create a hashtable using powershell syntax, then convert that object into Json. eg

```
$pram = @{
   name= "MDE.Windows";
   id= "$resourceId/extensions/MDE.Windows";
 } | ConvertTo-Json
```

You can now pass the json encoded value of `$parm` to `Invoke-WebRequest`.

The other option is to create a String and write the JSON yourself:

```
$paramString = '{"id":  "/extensions/MDE.Windows", "name":  "MDE.Windows"}'
```

(but the first solution is probably the solution your looking for).